# I want to redirect to Magento Pages (Product/Categories etc.) only if Customer is Logged in. Otherwise it Should Redirect to Customer Login page

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

When I'm not Logged in and hitting HomePage of Magento(magento2.test), It redirects to Customer Login Page. This is Absolutely Correct.

But When I'm hitting a Category Page like(http://magento2.test/men/tops-men/tees-men.html), I'm getting a White Screen with this Error ("502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.19.0").

I'm attaching relevent code files.

events.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
   <config xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd'>
       <event name='controller_action_predispatch'>
            <observer name='checklogin' instance='Vendor\Module\Observer\MyObserver'/>
       </event>
   </config>
```

MyObserver.php

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getFullActionName();
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $openActions = array(
    'create',
    'createpost',
    'login',
    'loginpost',
    'logoutsuccess',
    'forgotpassword',
    'forgotpasswordpost',
    'resetpassword',
    'resetpasswordpost',
    'confirm',
    'confirmation'
    );

    if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface */
        $urlInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
        $url = $urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');
        if(strpos($request->getPathInfo(), '/customer/account/') !== 0)
        {
            $observer->getControllerAction()
                ->getResponse()
                ->setRedirect($url);
        }
    }

    if ($controller == 'account' && in_array($actionName, $openActions)) {
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code you can check customer login or not anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
else{
   // customer Not login action
}
```

From controller

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // customer login action
}
```

Comment: if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) is doing the same thing but it is working for some pages and not working for some pages.